# How to get an alert whenver data over lan connection stops flowing?

Tags: networking, lan

So, there is a computer in an ICS environment, sending data to a server; time to time it has occurred that data stopped for some time and I need to ensure it could be monitored and an action can be taken.

I need to find a solution to basically monitor the network connection and generate and audible sound in case data stops or connection drops for any reason.

Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: There are open source and paid-for tools that offer this. You could also do something as simple as writing a script that pings the host in question. What research have you done regarding this and what have you tried?

Comment: There are tools such as Zabbix (https://www.zabbix.com/) and alternatives, https://alternativeto.net/software/zabbix/